# CLI for ffmpeg and multiple GPU card

Tags: ffmpeg, opencl

I have multiple GPU video card, how do I tell ffmpeg to use certain video card for video compression.  Right now I type in ffmpeg -i infile.mp4 -c:v libx264 -x264opts opencl, does ffmpeg allocate the first device that support opencl?

Comment: No, there is no opencl decoder support in ffmpeg command line for now.

Answer (score 0):

There is some info here https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro specifically to use *-hwaccel_device* but it's CUDA related

Comment: `hwaccel` is a general concept related to several interfaces. It hasn't to be cuda.